# Call overridden function from a System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, reflection, entity-framework-4.1

I have an extension method I'm trying to make generic, for message passing.

```
    public static ActionResult RedirectCompanyMessage<T>(this Controller controller, T mObject, Company company)
    {
        var msg = mObject.ToString()
        ...
    }
```

the `mObject.ToString()` is returning junk like `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.SerialCode_960A5FEF6FE5426EE5F55B8627454C71E7D088921143DE49B208E7FED043ADA5`

But, the base type (the proxy type?) has an overridden ToString().

```
public partial class SerialCode
{
    //Prints the serial code with dashes every 5 chars
    public new String ToString()
    {
        return Utility.Utility.FormatSerial(this.Serial);
    }
}
```

So, what's the deal? During debugging, if I hover over "T", visual studio shows `T mObject` as the correct `Models.SerialCode`, but if I run `mObject.GetType()` in the immediate window I see `FullName = "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.SerialCode_960A5F...`

I just want to be able to reliably run the overridden ToStrings() in all my partial classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't "override" `.ToString()`; you reintroduced it with `new`. If you want to override, use `override`, not `new`.

Comment: Upvote for now - that solved the problem, but I'm still confused about the discrepancy between visual studio debugging tools and the immediate window. Why did they still run the "new ToString()" when the immediate window wouldn't? Is that just a case where VS hasn't caught up with the EF4.1 POCO magic?

Comment: No, it's that by using `new` you're defeating OO polymorphism, and you'll get different results with references of different types to the same instance. Mostly you almost never want to use `new` for anything, and by avoiding it you'll not have to think about why its behavior is confusing.

Comment: I was trying to figure out why I typed new and not override in the first place. Apparently when you type `public string ToString()`, the first ReSharper hint AND the default visual studio tooltip is to suggest using new, and not override.

Comment: Although, I am going to read up on new a bit more, so I can understand why its behavior is confusing - I started programming because I like thinking and understanding abstract concepts; I'm not going to run away from confusing things.